# Productivity tracking software for Windows 10

Tags: windows, time-management, productivity

I am working on my productivity and I am using a 30-minutes-no-interruptions technique (also known as *pomodoro technique*). Currently I am using my smartphone to countdown time.

I would like software to be more comprehensive:

- to remember how much time I spent working on a particular day;
- show a timer above all windows (virtually painted over the screen) that shows how much time is left from a 30-minutes frame.

This will help me stay motivated (I can check what are my productivity improvements over time) and will not require additional device to track my productivity frames.

Comment: Did you check [pomodairo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pomodairo/)? It fulfills your second reqiurement.